# FileNotFoundException with 404 code when trying to reach html page

Tags: java, http, download, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to download links from this site:
http://prices.shufersal.co.il

When I try to download it myself from the site It's work fine,
But when I'm trying to download the link from the code, it's saying the FileNotFoundException - 404 status code.

Here is a link for for example:
http://pricesprodpublic.blob.core.windows.net/price/Price7290027600007-001-201601290030.gz?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=1ksETqGvmSbWGnqQ6NgPGCqfsX4r%2BluSvcmf%2F1ppj8Q%3D&se=2016-01-28T23%3A24%3A43Z&sp=r

I think each time you requesting the page it's giving different download links,
but still I can not download it from the code.

This is my code:

```
public void download() {
    for (int currType = 1; currType <= ShufersalConstants.TYPES.size(); currType++) {
        String link = BASE_URL + CAT_MODIFIER + currType + MODIFIER_SEPERATOR + STORE_MODIFIER + 0;

        StringBuilder a = HttpUtils.sendGetRequest(link);

        System.out.println(a.toString());

        fetchLinks(a.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public ArrayList<String> fetchLinks(String htmlPage) {
    Logger.log("Fetching the links from the HTML page");

    // Creating new list that will hold all the links for the .gz files
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Getting the start position of the first download link
    int startLinkPos = htmlPage.indexOf("http://pricesprodpublic.blob.core.windows.net");

    // Getting the end position of the first download link
    int endLinkPos = htmlPage.indexOf(" target=", startLinkPos);

    // Running over the string until there are no more download links
     while (startLinkPos != -1) {
         links.add(htmlPage.substring(startLinkPos, endLinkPos - 1));

         HttpUtils.getGZStream(htmlPage.substring(startLinkPos, endLinkPos - 1));

     // Returning the list of links
     return (links);
}
```

The HttpUtils class doing a regular request to the url.

This is the method in the HttpUtils class:

```
/**
 * The function gets GZ file from the link that the function gets
 * @param link The link for the GZ file
 * @return GZStream to use with
 */
public static GZIPInputStream getGZStream(String link) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    GZIPInputStream gzStream = null;

    try {
        // Create connection using the link we get as a parameter
        URL url = new URL(link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Get the response from the connection after sending the request
        InputStream is = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();

        // Creating the GZ stream base on the InputStream
        gzStream = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.logError("An ERROR occured while trying to get GZ stream");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Returning the response
    return (gzStream);
}
```

Can someone help me writing such thing?
I'm really stuck and need to download that files..

Thanks.

Comment: can i suggest posting what url the program generates at the end of this - the one that gives the 404. Does it generate the correct links?

Comment: Yes, the link that I geIt from the html is a correct link, when I copy it into the browser it works.

Comment: OK, so its a case of the program not executing and retrieving using the generated url?

Comment: Yes, I think there is something in the connection that it's not succeeding to retrive the url

Comment: would it not be better to build a list of the links, then itterate over that list executing each one seperatly that way?

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do, but right now I can not execute even one of them. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: well, assuming that `links` holds strings of each correct url, why not use a while loop and `links.get(i)` as the parameter for `HttpUtils.getGZStream()` ?

Comment: This is not the probleam, I should do like you say. I just can't get the GZStream for even one link.

Comment: Have you tried manually entering a link into your `HttpUtils.getGZStream()` function to see if it even runs?

Comment: Yes, I did it but with gz file from other site. What can cause Java to throw FileNotFoundException for existing file?